# Show modal dialog window

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I am using IE 7 ASP.net C#.

In my page i am opening show modal dialog window, in this window i have a link to open a show modal doalog window. Second window has a save button.

On clicking this button this opens the same window unnecessarily.

Any suggestion?

Code for Save Button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnsave_Click" ValidationGroup="save"
                                            CausesValidation="true" class="button_popups" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<base target="_self" />
```

This was required in the head tag of the problem window